# Installing tensorflow for Python 2.7 when already have for Python 3.5

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I have tensorflow already installed for Python 3.5 in Ubuntu 16.04, and when I import it, I get the following message:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>>>
```

But with Python2.7, I get this:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

I tried to install tensorflow after installing cuDNN, Cuda, bumblebee, nvidia driver etc., but after I rebooted, I couldn't get past the login screen. After a friend of mine fixed the problem, I still wanna use tensorflow with Python 2.7, how can I do so without messing up my system? I have cuda 9.1 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `virtualenv` to manage your pip packages? you can easily use it to avoid multi-version of tensorflow and Python,

Comment: No, can you please give me and direct me to the instructions that will allow me to do so?

Comment: @Always Learning Forever, You can install `virtualenv` by run `$ pip install virtualenv`, and then run `$ virtualenv [Your_VirtualEnv_Dir]` to create a dir called `[Your_VirtualEnv_Dir]` under your current directory which is the virtual environment with a default python version `Pyrhon 2.x`, then you can cd into the `[Your_VirtualEnv_Dir]/bin` directory and activate the virtualenv by running `activate.sh` or the `source` command depend on your OS, then you can directly install `tensorflow` just by running your `pip`, and all the install and modification will happened under VirtualEnv not in OS

Comment: OMG! Thank you thank you thank you! That worked like a charm, I was trying to get this damn thing to work for a million years. Imma go find me a tutorial on virtualenv